# How to override / extend local extension model in magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise, extensions, overrides

I got a problem in overriding magento model local extension.

Here is my module config:

etc/modules/Mycompany_OrderExport.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_OrderExport>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                 <Xtento_OrderExport />
            </depends>
        </Mycompany_OrderExport>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And here is my extension config: app/code/local/Mycompany/OrderExport/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_OrderExport>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_OrderExport>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models> 
            <orderexport>
                <class>Mycompany_OrderExport_Model</class>
            </orderexport>
            <xtento_orderexport> 
                <rewrite>
                     <export_data_shared_items>Mycompany_OrderExport_Model_Xtento_Export_Data_Shared_Items</export_data_shared_items> 
                 </rewrite>
             </xtento_orderexport> 
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

and here is my model:

```
<?php
class Mycompany_OrderExport_Model_Xtento_Export_Data_Shared_Items extends Xtento_OrderExport_Model_Export_Data_Shared_Items
{
    public function getExportData($entityType, $collectionItem)
    {

        echo 'Override';
        die(1);
    }
}
?>
```

I would like to know where part I have missed on my script ? Because when I execute my script there's nothing's happen. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the part that makes problem here.

```
    <Mycompany_OrderExport>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
             <Xtento_OrderExport />
        </depends>
    </Mycompany_OrderExport>
```

You have disabled your module by setting the `active` node as `false`. Turn it on. Means put `true` for active. Make sure module is enabled through admin side. You can do this by go to

```
 System  >  Configuration  >  Advanced
```

Clear all cache and then try again.