# Overriding third party extension modules model not working (local on local override)

Tags: extensions, overrides, model

I've created a small module

app/code/local/Mycompany/Managa/config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config> 

<modules>
    <Mycompany_Managa>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Mycompany_Managa>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <mana_filters>
            <rewrite>
                   <managa>Mycompany_Managa_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute</managa>
            </rewrite>
        </mana_filters>
    </models>
</global>

</config>
```

app/code/local/Mycompany/Managa/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php

```
  class Mycompany_Managa_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute extends Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute
{
  //exact copy of Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute
 }
```

app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Managa.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
 <modules>
    <Mycompany_Managa>

        <active>true</active>

        <codePool>local</codePool>

        <depends>
            <Mana_Filters/>
        </depends>

    </Mycompany_Managa>
</modules>


</config>
```

The file that I'm trying to override is located at `/app/code/local/Mana/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php` and as mentioned above it has a class - `Mana_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute`.

I assume it's something to do with my config file but no matter what I do I can't seem to get the site to use my version of the model. I've followed other questions with similar questions such as - [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942050/magento-how-to-override-a-model-in-a-local-module),[two](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36723/how-to-override-extend-local-extension-model-in-magento) and [three](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/), but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are lot of issue  on you code

### 1. Folder Structure ISSUE:

There are only two folder Upto Model folder:

Need change folder stucture

**From:**

```
Mycompany/Managa/Filters/Model/Filter/Attribute.php
```

**TO:**

```
Mycompany/Managa/Model/Filter/Attribute.php
```

Need to change  at Class name accordingly:

```
Mycompany_Managa_Filters_Model_Filter_Attribute
```

**TO**

```
Mycompany_Managa_Model_Filter_Attribute
```

## 2.Third Party Model Prefix issue:

You need to checked first Mana_Filters Model prefix:

in Mana_Filters Config.xml check models prefix.

```
  <models>
    <model_prefix> <!-- This is call  Model Prefix -->
        <class>Mana_Filters</class>
    </model_prefix> <!-- This is call  Model Prefix -->
    </models>
```

**Config.xml**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <mana_filters> <!-- Check  Manadev Filter Prefix -->
            <rewrite>
                   <filter_attribute>Mycompany_Managa_Model_Filter_Attribute</filter_attribute>
            </rewrite>
        </mana_filters>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Amit. I've updated the model path and class. Also changed the reference in the config.xml to match the new class name. mana_filters is also correct but it's still not working

Comment: Ignore that, i posted it before your last update. Thank you! This works a treat.